# Replacing first number of a file for its half

Tags: awk, sed

I have a series of files that have two number in the first line (i.e. 170 1742) and then several other lines. If I want to just replace, in every file, the first number for its half (i.e. 85 1742) how would I do that in Unix?

Comment: post some input fragments (from several files) and desired result

Comment: How may those numbers be expressed? Integer only, or can things like 23.45 or 3.2e9 or even 0x22 be found? Assuming positive decimal integer only, what should happen for odd numbers (should we get 7/2 = 3 (integer) or 7/2 = 3.5)?

Comment: Whilst you *could* do this with Sed, the division will be much easier with Awk or Perl...

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -pi -e 's|\d+|$&/2|e if $. == 1; close ARGV if eof' ./*.txt
```

Would replace the first sequence of decimal digits on the first line of every non-hidden `txt` file in the current directory, with the canonical decimal representation of half the corresponding number (3 for 006, 3.5 for 007 for instance).

If the number is very big (like greater than 1e20), `perl` may switch to engineering notation (5e+19).

Obviously that approach is only valid for decimal integer numbers. When applied to `.1` it would give `.5` instead of `0.05`; when applied to 1.5, it would give `0.5.5` instead of `0.75`; when applied to `0x10`, it would give `0x10` (only `0` is halved) instead of 8 or 0x8 and so on.

If you wanted to handle decimal numbers in any notation (1, 010 (meaning 10, not octal 8), -1.123, 2.23e-4, inf, infinity, NaN...)), you'd need to adapt the matching regular expression, like:

```
s{(\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?)(e[-+]?\d+)?|nan|inf(inity)?}{$&/2}ie
```

Or make some assumption on where the number is on the line, like if it's the first sequence of non-spacing characters:

```
s{\S+}{$&/2}e
```

Comment: `close ARGV` can also be written as `$. = 0` with the same condition upon `eof`

Comment: Also the regex would miss out floats of the form: `mmm.nnn`. We can write it as: `(?:\d+(?:[.]\d*)?|[.]\d+)(?:e[-+]?\d+)?` to make it water tight.

Comment: @Rakesh, why would it miss them out? Or maybe you're refering to an older version of my answer where I had `\d|\d*\.\d+` forgetting that perl RE as opposed to ERE don't go for the longest match in alternations but give preference to the left-most ones.

Comment: Oops, my wording is bad: I meant it would miss out `mmm.` type of floats, e.g., `534.`

Comment: @Rakesh, ah OK thanks. I've now addressed it by adding a `\.?` on the `\d+` part.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
awk 'FNR==1{print $1/2,$2;next}1' ./*.txt #or /directory/* or just file.txt
```

Or even

```
awk 'FNR==1{$1=$1/2}1' file1
```

Above awk will print the corresponding results on your screen or you can redirect the modified output to a new file using `>newfile`

With GNU awk , you can apply changes directly in your original file using [gnu awk inplace option:](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html)

```
awk -i inplace 'FNR==1{$1=$1/2}1' file1
```

If your awk does not support inplace , you can do it manually like

```
 awk 'FNR==1{$1=$1/2}1' file > newfile && mv newfile file
```

This is actually what awk (and even sed) inplace editing does under the hood.

Comment: GNU `sed -i` or `awk -i inplace` (or `perl -i` which is the one that started it) would try to copy some of the file's metadata to the newfile though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas GNU sed man pages makes no reference about this metadata capability. But if you have checked it , ok. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html?--in-place#index-GNU-extensions_002c-in_002dplace-editing

Comment: Without it, the permissions of the new file for instance would be based on the current umask instead of being copied from the original file. So you'd potentially be widening access to the file which could be a serious issue (there still are issues for attributes that sed can't restore like ownership, or when the file is a symlink)

Comment: Also beware [using gawk -i inplace like that introduces a security vulnerability](/q/749645) unless you modify `$AWKPATH` not to include `.` or make sure you run that command from within a working directory where nobody could create a file called `inplace` or `inplace.awk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tempd=$(mktemp -d)
for f in ./*.csv
do
   < "$f" \
       sed -e '1y/\t-/ _/; 1!s/.*/[&]/' |
       dc -e '
       [q]sq
       [?z0=q pc z0=?]s? # macro "?" to print line
       ?r2/ n32anpc l?x  # 1st line div/2 the last stack elem print it+spc+2nd
      ' \
   > "$tempd/$f"
   mv "$tempd/$f" .
done
rm -r "$tempd"
```